# how to pass the variables through a javascript function when it is written inside the php echo statement

Tags: javascript, php

how to pass the variables through a javascript function when it is written inside the php echo statement .

here my code

problem with quotes

```
 echo '<a style="color:green" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:chatWith('$u_code','$u_name')" >'.$u_name.'</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest option by using `\DOMDocument`:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$e = $dom->createElement('a', $u_name);
$a = $dom->appendChild($e);
$a->setAttribute('style',   'color: green;');
$a->setAttribute('href',    'javascript:void(0);');
$a->setAttribute('onclick', 'chatWith("' . $u_code . '","' . $u_name . '");');

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape those quotes:

```
echo '<a style="color:green" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:chatWith(\''.$u_code.'\',\''.$u_name.'\')" >'.$u_name.'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append your php variables with "." and escape quotes

```
 echo '<a style="color:green" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:chatWith(\''.$u_code.'\',\''.$u_name.'\')" >'.$u_name.'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<a style="color:green" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:chatWith('.$u_code.','.$u_name.')" >'.$u_name.'</a>';
```

Comment: @BenFortune we can use like this "'.$u_code.'" if its string..right?

Comment: If the javascript `chatWith()` function takes arguments as a string, they need to be wrapped in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the quotes

```
echo '<a style="color:green" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:chatWith(\''.$u_code.'\',\''.$u_name.'\')" >'.$u_name.'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a style=\"color:green\" 
         href=\"javascript:void(0)\" 
         onclick=\"javascript:chatWith('".$u_code."','".$u_name."')\" 
         >'.$u_name.'</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the quotes in your statement.

```
echo '<a style="color:green" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:chatWith(\''.$u_code.'\',\''.$u_name.'\')" >'.$u_name.'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, we should just close PHP, improves readability AND you don't get stuck in nested quotes.

```
?>

<a style="color: green"
   href="javascript: void(0);"
   onclick="javascript: chatWith('<?php echo $u_code; ?>','<?php echo $u_name; ?>');">
    <?php echo $u_name; ?>
</a>

<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, which is cleaner

```
$link = '<a onclick="javascript:chatWith({ucode},{uname})" style="color:green" href="javascript:void(0)">{anchor}</a>';

 $link = str_replace(
 $q = "'";
array('{ucode}', '{uname}', '{anchor}'), 
      array($q.$u_code.$q, $q.$u_name.$q, $uname), 
      $link
    );

echo $link;
```

Comment: This isn't even cleaner. It's less readable. You go even better by using `{$u_code}` which renders instant variable.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I think for an average programmer its very readable as its very easy to maintain and add more items

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
echo '<a style="color:green" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:chatWith('.$u_code.','.$u_name.')" >'.$u_name.'</a>';
```

Answer (score -1):

Your formatting seems to be off.

```
echo '<a style="color:green" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:chatWith(\''.$u_code.'\',\''.$u_name.'\')" >'.$u_name.'</a>';
```

the `.` is used to append variables to a string in PHP, since you are using single quotes you'll have to escape the string every time you insert a variable.

Hope this helped.

‐ Sid